# How do I include a .gitignore file as part of my npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, scaffolding

I am building an npm module that will generate a specific project template for certain software projects.  As such, when a developer installs my npm module and runs it, I would like the program to create files and folders in a certain way.

One such file I would like to include in the project template is a .gitignore file because the software project is going to assume it will be tracked via git.  However, when I call "npm install" on my module, npm renames all my .gitignore files to .npmignore files.  How can I ensure that my .gitignore files are not tampered with by npm when I distribute my module?

Answer (score 4):

Currently npm doesn't allow `.gitignore` files to be included as part of an npm package and will instead rename it to `.npmignore`.

A common workaround is to rename the `.gitignore` to `gitignore` before publishing. Then as part of an init script, rename the `gitignore` file to `.gitignore`. This approach is used in `Create React App`

Here's how to do it in Node, code from [Create React App init script](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/2da5517689b7510ff8d8b0148ce372782cb285d7/packages/react-scripts/scripts/init.js#L264-L278)

```js
  const gitignoreExists = fs.existsSync(path.join(appPath, '.gitignore'));
  if (gitignoreExists) {
    // Append if there's already a `.gitignore` file there
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(appPath, 'gitignore'));
    fs.appendFileSync(path.join(appPath, '.gitignore'), data);
    fs.unlinkSync(path.join(appPath, 'gitignore'));
  } else {
    // Rename gitignore after the fact to prevent npm from renaming it to .npmignore
    // See: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1862
    fs.moveSync(
      path.join(appPath, 'gitignore'),
      path.join(appPath, '.gitignore'),
      []
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1862

Looks like this is a known issue. The answer at the bottom seems like the recommended approach. In case the issue or link ever gets destroyed:

> For us, I think a better solution is going to be clear documentation that if authors wish to use .gitignore in their generators, they will need to name their files .##gitignore##, which will be a value gitignore set to the same string gitignore.
>
> In this way, the file that gets published as a template file to npm is called .##gitignore## and won't get caught by npm, but then later it gets replaced with the string to be .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

You can see multiple commits dealing with [npm issue 1862](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1862):

- [this project adds a `rename.json`](https://github.com/spmjs/spm/commit/a3633818d344126042ea5f9ee77d41b7e940a48d):

  ```
  lib/init-template/rename.json
  {
      ".npmignore": ".gitignore",
  }
  ```
- [this one renames the `.gitignore`](https://github.com/cortexjs/cortex-scaffold-generator/commit/fa14a7cb16b5b82213b2d11819d0f03903cc1383):

  ```
  templates/default/.gitignore → templates/default/{%=gitignore%}

  index.js
  @@ -114,6 +114,10 @@ generator._pkgData = function (pkg) {
      + // npm will rename .gitignore to .npmignore:
      + // [ref](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1862)
      + pkg.gitignore = '.gitignore';
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: even though this answer causes `.gitignore` to be included in the published package (proven by [unpkg](https://unpkg.com)), upon running `npm install` the `.gitignore` file is simply *removed*! So even getting NPM to include the file is not enough.

Another solution (simpler imo):

Include both `.gitignore` *and* `.npmignore` in the repo. Add the following to your `.npmignore` file:

```
!.gitignore
!.npmignore
```

Now that `.npmignore` will already exist in the published package, NPM won't rename `.gitignore`.

Comment: It doesn't work.